# Apache Kafka SSE connector does not receive any events

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to build a Kafka SSE connector, which would stream  Wikipedia updates into a Kafka topic. I'm using the Apache CXF client for the SSE part, but have also tried Jersey with the same result.

I'm testing this in a local docker-compose with 1 Kafka, 1 Connect and 1 zookeeper.
The problem is that when I run the (unit) test for the connect task, I can see that it is receiving SSE events and converting them to source records. However when I try to run this locally in a Docker compose, it never sees any events. I opened a shell inside the Connect docker and verified that connectivity is there (curl to the SSE url receives events).
I'm aware of github.com/cjmatta/kafka-connect-sse, however that project does not build anymore when I clone it. I compared the code and don't see that much of a difference, except for the client library used. I'm wondering if there is anything internally in Connect that is keeping my setup from working.

The complete project (including compose and build instructions) is here: https://github.com/tonvanbart/kafka-connect-example - if anyone could shed some light on this I'd be very grateful as I'd like to understand what the problem is.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: moin Ton, did you ever figure out your problem?

Comment: I finally managed to partly track it down, a NullPointerException occurs in CXF AbstractClient in line 937. There is some classloading weirdness in Connect and I'm sure I'm missing something in the task classpath, but could not track down what.
When I ran Connect in my IDE everything worked, found the issue by attaching a remote debugger to the Connect node.
I took out Apache CXF and switched to Java 11 `HttpClient` which has SSE support, now the connector works fine. It's on a branch, I'll merge that to `master` shortly.